# What are the best strategies to kill Phylakes when underleveled?

Tags: assassins-creed-origins

In Assassin's Creed Origins, the leveling system is such that 3 levels below an enemy, you take double damage and deal half damage. 5 levels and you deal practically no damage to an enemy.

What are some ways to defeat the roaming Phylakes bosses when 3 levels below them? Is it possible to defeat them when you're 5 levels below?

Comment: I climb way up high and shoot them with arrows (I've also over-invested in archery upgrades). Bows that inflict bonus damage (fire, poison) come in useful here.

Comment: I guess whatever you do some levels below it'll still be hard, but the main strat is exploiting there attacks as they are repeated in patterns and kill them slowly.